# Obtain all input[name='item[]'] in jQuery to pass all selected products via AJAX

Tags: jquery

I am using the colorbox plugin in jQuery. This allows you to pass data throw a variable 'data' using the same syntax on jQuery.load(), like:

```
$("#example").colorbox({
    data: { foo: "bar" },
    href: "/example"
});
```

My problem is that I need a complex way of passing the data: there is more than one case. The HTML where you will call the colorbox function contains a with:

- Select between QUANTITY or SERVICES.
- - If you select QUANTITY, you have to fill a PRICE.
- - If you fill SERVICES, you have to check (checkboxes) various items in a list (with name="item[]").
- Name destinatary
- Name sender
- Message

My problem is that I don't know how to define this variables dynamically, let me explain. In the href variable case I can do something like:

```
$("#example").colorbox({
    data: { foo: "bar" },
    href: function() {
         var url = "/example"; // A useless example, but I can do a function here
         return url;
    }
});
```

There is anyway I can reproduce this inside the **{ }** of data?

For example:

```
<input type="radio" name="amount" value="1" /> Quantity
<input type="radio" name="amount" value="0" /> Services

<input type="text" name="quantity" value="" /> Insert a quantity
```

Is `$("input[name='amount']:checked").val() == 1`, I need to pass:

```
{ amount: 1, quantity: quantity_inserted }
```

In the other case, the val() == 0:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="12_32" /> Item #12
<input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="13_32" /> Item #13 <- checked
<input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="14_32" /> Item #14 <- checked
<input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="15_32" /> Item #15
<input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="16_32" /> Item #16
<input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="17_32" /> Item #17 <- checked
<input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="18_32" /> Item #18 <- ehecked
```

I need to pass:

```
{ amount: 0, items: array_of_values }
```

How I can do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you need all inputs with name 'item[]'? That's easy:

```
$( 'input:checkbox[name="item[]"]:checked' )
```